# MemoryStream.SetLength(0) and MemoryStream.Capacity = 0 don't clear used memory

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, memorystream

I have a program that streams media, which creates two huge MemoryStreams, and then needs to zero them when done. The problem is, the memory does not seem to be reclaimed after I call BOTH MemoryStream.SetLength(0); and MemoryStream.Capacity = 0. GC.Collect() seems to solve the problem, but I have heard this is bad programming practice, because it causes all threads in the application to hang; although hung threads would not be a problem for the short time it would take to clear the memory. However, it would be nice if there was another workaround to the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Another workaround is to play several memory-intensive video games on the computer for a while, and then the GC seems to start working, or use an UnmanagedMemoryStream and clear it using unmanaged commands.

Comment: You are looking at "working set", a deeply meaningless number.  Don't use task manager.

Comment: I'm not; I'm using process explorer.

Comment: the GC clears the memory not immediately... it takes into account memory usage and several other factors to influence the app as little as possible... why do you want the memory immediately collected ?

Comment: Because it may be distracting to a tech-savvy user who notices that the application is using 125MB of RAM when it's not even doing anything.

Comment: Well, don't worry, that tech-savvy user will be eager to explain it to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> GC.Collect() seems to solve the problem

So there is no problem... Why do you think you need to force the GC to collect the memory at once? It will be done when the system deems it necessary. Don't try to outsmart the GC ;)

Comment: For the reason in the comment above. A tech-savvy user of the program might notice that it is using an unusually large amount of RAM for an idle application that isn't streaming anything.

Comment: Well, most "big" apps do the same... look at the memory consumption of a web browser

Comment: Anyway, if it bothers you, you can always call GC.Collect explicitly, if you know what you're doing... just don't do it while your app is doing a lot of work

Answer (score 0):

You can just fill the memory with zeros with the Write method, then call Flush, then call the MemoryStream's Close or Dispose method, if you're worried that the data remaining in the stream will remain in memory after it's disposed. (Yes, it will be slower for huge memory streams, but you should only be concerned of this after determining, through profiling, whether it causes a real performance problem in your program.)

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need manual management of the memory, use [`UnmanagedMemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.aspx) with memory allocated by something like `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call dispose on the memory streams? Otherwise i would say that unless perf is unacceptable when you do a gc.collect, go ahead and do it. We had a similar situation where the customer found the "let the gc do its thing" explanation unacceptable. Esp if it does no harm, do what the customer wants.